# CSS circle border increase/decrease according to the number it contains

Tags: javascript, html, css

I seek a way for something that ultimately seems simple enough ... but I did not manage yet!

The idea I have of numbers (in span) located inside circle css. I wish that the edge of my circle changes according to the number it contains.

For example: if the number is between 0 and 10, the border = 2px
if the number is between 10 and 20, the border = 4px
so on ...

I expect your help, thank you!

PS : the same idea when the span is outside of my cercle PLZ :)

Comment: Can you add related HTML/CSS/JS?

Answer (score 0):

Here an example that may help you:

```
$(".s").each(function() {
   var text = parseInt($(this).text());
    if ( text > 0 && text <= 10 ) {
        $(this).addClass("border-2");
    } else if ( text > 10 && text <= 20 ) {
        $(this).addClass("border-4");
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="s">9</span>
<span class="s">5</span>
<span class="s">15</span>
```

**css**

```
.s {
    display: block;
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.border-2 {
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.border-4 {
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hrbnrkqa/

Comment: Very interesting, thanks ! In other hand i have other circles with img inside and the number below the circle, if i want the circle to increase/decrease according to this number below ? Theres a way ?

Comment: And you adapt this code as you like! :) It's not difficult

Comment: even if the css variation is not on the span himself but on other element

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to implement JavaScript on your page? If so you're probably best off inspecting the value of the span and adjusting the css accordingly.

ie.
    var valueOfSpan = $('#idOfSpan').val()
    if (valueOfSpan > 0 && valueOfSpan <= 10)
    $('#idOfSpan').css("border-radius", "2px");

Comment: Thanks nick but doesnt seems to work, fiddle please ? var valueOfSpan = $('.circle').val(); if (valueOfSpan > 0 && valueOfSpan <= 100) $('.circle').css("border-radius", "10px");

Answer (score 0):

Do you want only those specific steps, or were they examples for a general behavior?
This fiddle works fine for me for the latter:
https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/xn7s3700/

```js
$(".borderbycontent").each(function(){
   $(this).css("border-radius", $(this).html()/5); 
});
```

```css
.borderbycontent{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#ddd;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="borderbycontent">
    5
</div><div class="borderbycontent">
    10
</div><div class="borderbycontent">
    20
</div><div class="borderbycontent">
    30
</div><div class="borderbycontent">
    60
</div>
```

otherwise, just take the value and check for the ranges with switch/case, for example.

Comment: And if the value is 9?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina well this would result in a radius of 1.8 with this exact setup (depending on browser capabilities there may or may not be a difference between this and 2px)... Depending on what the behavior should really be, a check for the specific ranges might be necessary, as I and others have pointed out

Comment: So you should round the value

Comment: Of course, that would be a safe way (if that is even the right direction to go in, I think it might be desired here to have a fixed value between certain ranges. Which would of course also be something you might achieve using rounding or flooring, and multiplying afterwards )

Answer (score 0):

Select all elements, loop over collection and calculate new border radius value:

```js
/**
 * Algorithm to calculate new radius
 * Number ranges progression: 0:10 - 2, 10:20 - 4, 20:30 - 6, 30:40 - 8, etc.
 * Get top boundary of the range and devide by 5.
 */
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.smart-border')).forEach(function(span) {
    var number = Number(span.textContent.trim());
    var newBorder = Math.ceil(number / 10) * 10 / 5;
    span.style.borderRadius = newBorder + 'px';
});
```

```css
.smart-border {
    border: 2px #1D9B28 solid;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #CFBB92;
    line-height: 3;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="smart-border">5</span>
<span class="smart-border">15</span>
<span class="smart-border">21</span>
<span class="smart-border">36</span>
```

Comment: _Math.ceil(number / 10) * 10 / 5;_? wouldn't it be neater to just write _Math.ceil(number / 10) * 2;_?

Comment: @BenPhilipp I left it like this so that formula is clear how radius is calculated. But of course it can be simplified.